# Creating relationships based on nested list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm building a graph based and some of the relationships are based on information in nested lists. The relevant nodes are (b:Bundle) and (o:Object); the bundles require certain objects with different quantities and qualities. The nested list that contains these requirements has the format
    `[ [object1, quantity1, quality1], [object2, quantity2, quality2], ... ]`
but in the .csv file that I'm using the field has the format
`o1,qn1,ql1|o2,qn2,ql2|...`
    The relationship I want to create is 
`(b)-[r:REQUIRES {quantity, quality}]->(o)`.

I've tried using various combinations of SPLIT, UNWIND, and FOREACH. A minimal example from my data set:

> id: 1 
>   requirements: 24,1,0|188,1,0|190,1,0|192,1,0

That is to say, `(b:Bundle {id:1}) -[r:REQUIRES {quantity:1, quality:0}]-> (o:Object {id:24})` and so on.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///bundles.csv' AS line
    WITH SPLIT( UNWIND SPLIT ( line.requirements, '|' ), ',') as reqList
    MATCH ( o:Object { id:TOINTEGER(reqList[0]) } )
    MATCH ( b:Bundle { id:TOINTEGER(line.id) } )    
    MERGE (b) -[r:REQUIRES]-> (o)
    ON CREATE SET r.quantity = TOINTEGER(reqList[1]),
                  r.quality = TOINTEGER(reqList[2]);
```

The error this query gives is

> `Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'P': expected 't/T' (line 2, column 22 (offset: 78))
>   "   WITH SPLIT( UNWIND SPLIT ( line.requirements, '|' ), ',') as reqList"
>                         ^`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your CSV file actually looks like this:

```
id requirements
1 24,1,0|188,1,0|190,1,0|192,1,0
```

then this query should work:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///bundles.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ' '
WITH line.id AS id, SPLIT(line.requirements, '|' ) AS reqsList
UNWIND reqsList AS reqsString
WITH id, SPLIT(reqsString, ',') AS reqs
MATCH ( o:Object { id:TOINTEGER(reqs[0]) } )
MATCH ( b:Bundle { id:TOINTEGER(id) } )    
MERGE (b) -[r:REQUIRES]-> (o)
ON CREATE SET r.quantity = TOINTEGER(reqs[1]),
              r.quality = TOINTEGER(reqs[2]);
```

Comment: Using your query exactly as is didn't return it an error, but it did return (no changes, no records). However, it worked perfectly without the FIELDTERMINATOR ' ' portion. I appreciate the help, I don't know how long I would have banged my head against this before I got it solved